# UIButton is 0x0000 when reload TableView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I added UIButton to each uitableview row but when i nedd reloadData, uibutton is 0x0000. Can you give me any suggestions? Thanks much.
I used this code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /*NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
  //  NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {*/
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        UILabel *pricelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 80, 30)];
        pricelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        pricelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        pricelabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        pricelabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        pricelabel.tag = 3000;
        //pricelabel.hidden = YES;
        pricelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: pricelabel];
        [pricelabel release];


        UIButton * market = [[UIButton alloc] init];;
        [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
         market.tag = 4000;

        [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        // [market setTag:indexPath.row];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:market];
    }


    if([priceNewArray count]> 0)
    {
        UILabel *pricelbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3000];
        pricelbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[priceNewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        if ([sellingArray count]>0) {
            if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"]){
                pricelbl.hidden = NO;
            }
            else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
                pricelbl.hidden = YES;

        }

    }


    }
    UIButton *marketButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4000];
    [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    if([sellingArray count]>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"sellingArray %@",sellingArray);
        if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
        {

            [marketButton setSelected:NO];
            [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            marketButton.enabled = YES;

        }
        else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])  // marketplace
        {

            [marketButton setSelected:YES];
            [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            marketButton.enabled = YES;

        }
    }

     _tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);

    return cell;
}
```

I used above code, when reloadData, data of Price label is changed fine but marketbutton can not changed image. I debug after call `[_tableview reloadData];`, marketButton is **0x0000** .

Comment: Why are you using a different cell identifier for each row? You're losing the benefit of cell recycling.  Where and how are you checking the value that you say is nil?

Comment: @Abizern: can you example code ? I'm a newbie. Thanks much

Comment: Not sample code but a hint.  It's a lot easier to design your custom cells on the Storyboard and add UI elements there rather than trying to do it in code.

Comment: Why are you retagging the button here, `[marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];`?

Comment: i thinks set tag for each button to get event of it.

Comment: Try using a static CellIdentifier. And let us know the result.

Comment: I tried using statis CellIndentifier but it still same

Answer (score 0):

I think your comparison is not correct. You are trying to compare integer with string.

If i asumed correct then try something like this.

```
int sellingPrice=0;

if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sellingPrice]]) // nothing

 sellingPrice=2;

else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sellingPrice]])  // marketplace
```

Comment: No, if comparison is not correct, Price label is still reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

use single CellIdentifier for cell when using same designs for cell,it used to reuse tableview cells

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"
```

please remove this code `[marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];` you not want to change tag for cell,you not set tag for **identifier** for `UIButton`, change this two thinks your code will work

Comment: If i remove [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row]; , when i press on marketbutton, my app is crash.

Comment: marketPressedAction method found in your class ? button image changed or not?

Comment: Yes , marketPressedAction method in my class? button image not changeed